# Change language pack of Forge Design Automation Autocad

Tags: autocad, forge, autodesk-designautomation

I want to switch Autocad engine of Design Automation from en-US to ja-JP.

I am having difficulty reading files with accoreconsole english package. I used ja-JP in acccoreconsole command but it failed.

The file read successfully with accoreconsole jp package in local machine, but failed on design automation.

```
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\31fb798920794a60b245a6dfcde5ab89\input.dxf" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.package" /s "T:\Aces\Jobs\31fb798920794a60b245a6dfcde5ab89\setting_script.scr" /l ja-JP]
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] Start script phase.
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] Start AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] Redirect stdout (file: T:\Aces\Jobs\31fb798920794a60b245a6dfcde5ab89\tmp\accc44122).
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] AcCoreConsole: StdOutConsoleMode: processed-output: disabled,auto
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] AutoCAD Core Engine Console - Copyright 2021 Autodesk, Inc.  All rights reserved. (S.51.Z.100)
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] Execution Path:
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] T:\Aces\AcesRoot\24.1\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] Current Directory: T:\Aces\Jobs\31fb798920794a60b245a6dfcde5ab89
[07/25/2022 01:45:56] Isolating to regkey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_31fb798920794a60b245a6dfcde5ab89, userDataFolder=T:\Aces\Jobs\31fb798920794a60b245a6dfcde5ab89\userdata.
[07/25/2022 01:45:57] Version Number: S.51.Z.100 (UNICODE)
[07/25/2022 01:45:57] LogFilePath has been set to the working folder.
[07/25/2022 01:45:57] Improper table entry name •Ç1ŠK on line 610.
[07/25/2022 01:45:57] Invalid or incomplete DXF input -- drawing discarded.
[07/25/2022 01:45:57] ERROR: Something went wrong. ErrorStatus=53.
```

Comment: Are you able to open the DXF file in AutoCAD Japnese ?

Comment: Yes, I can open it in AutoCAD Japanese.

Comment: Can you share the dxf file ? if it is confidential, please post it to forge.help@autodesk.com